# How to fill pickerView properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

i have an UIPickerView and i want it to have 2  columns filled with items from my arrays, but i cant figure out how, there is my arrays:

```
-(void)fillingStandartWeightArray{

    if (!standartWeightArray){
        for (int i=25; i<150 ;i++){
            NSString *weightString;
            weightString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d kg", i];
            [standartWeightArray addObject:weightString];
            NSLog(@"%@", weightString);
        }
    }

}

-(void)fillingStandartHeightArray{

    if (!standartHeightArray){
        for (int i=85; i<250; i++){
            NSString *heightString;
            heightString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d cm", i];
            [standartHeightArray addObject:heightString];
            NSLog(@"%@", heightString);
        }
    }

}
```

To be more specific i don't know how to "tell" UIPickerView to fill one of it wheel with one array, and other one with other array. I tried this:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{


    if (component == 0){
        return [standartWeightArray count];
    }   else {
        return [standartHeightArray count];
    }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{

    return 2;
}

-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    if (component == 0)
        return [standartWeightArray objectAtIndex:row];
    else if (component == 1)
        return [standartHeightArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

And  i did call functions in viewDidLoad sections:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self fillingStandartWeightArray];
    [self fillingStandartHeightArray];
    NSLog(@"%@", standartWeightArray);

}
```

But that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datasource/delegate methods are perfect.

Take care of following things

1) Allocating `standartHeightArray` and `standartWeightArray`  objects properly.  Allocate array objects as below if you are not doing already.

```
-(void)fillingStandartWeightArray{

    if (!standartWeightArray){
   // Allocate the array
       standartWeightArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i=25; i<150 ;i++){
            NSString *weightString;
            weightString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d kg", i];
            [standartWeightArray addObject:weightString];
            NSLog(@"%@", weightString);
        }
    }

}

-(void)fillingStandartHeightArray{

    if (!standartHeightArray){
   // Allocate the array
        standartHeightArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i=85; i<250; i++){
            NSString *heightString;
            heightString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d cm", i];
            [standartHeightArray addObject:heightString];
            NSLog(@"%@", heightString);
        }
    }

}
```

2) Connect the `delegate/datasource` properties of picker properly. You can do it in interface builder or in code (in `viewDidLoad`)

Comment: Yes, now it working, one little question, i am unfamiliar with that new syntax, is "new" equal to "alloc]init];"?

Comment: No difference. You can use either of them.

Answer (score 1):

Sure looks like you are setting everything up correctly to me.

But make sure you set the UIPickerView delegate and data source to the same object / class (ViewController?) where your PickerView data source methods live.

You can set this either in Xcode's Interface Builder, or at "`viewDidLoad:`" time programmatically (if you have your picker view set to an IBOutlet).

Comment: I guess i did connect it right, just because i see 2 empty "wheels" instead of one, i declare that it have to return 2 wheels..

Comment: if your picker wheels are empty, that's usually a sign your delegate and data source methods for the picker ***aren't*** set.

Comment: I did check and it settled. One more thing, there is a yellow warning in -(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component, that says - control reach end of non-void function. But, i did return values, why is that a warning like that?

Comment: well that certainly sounds like THE problem.  Can you edit your question to show the code for "`titleForRow:`"?  It sounds like there's at least one code path in there where you are returning with not even a NULL.